# Memory offsets in inline assembly

Tags: c, memory, assembly, inline-assembly, arm64

In A64 assembler, there are different ways to specify addresses.

```
/*
[base{,#0}]                 Simple register (exclusive) - Immediate Offset
[base{,#imm}]               Offset - Immediate Offset
[base,Xm{,LSL #imm}]        Offset - Register Offset
[base,Wm,(S|U)XTW {#imm}]   Offset - Extended Register Offset
[base,#imm]!                Pre-indexed - Immediate Offset
[base],#imm                 Post-indexed - Immediate Offset
label                       PC-relative (literal) load - Immediate Offset
*/
```

---

I would like to use "Offset - Immediate Offset" in inline assembler.

```
__asm__("ldp x8, x9, %0, 16 \n\t"
        :
        : "m" (*somePointer)
        : "x8", "x9");
```

This gets translated to

```
ldp x8, x9, [x0], 16
```

My goal is to reach

```
ldp x8, x9, [x0, 16]
```

**How can I write such instructions with inline assembler?**

Comment: I'm not sure how you can use %1 with only 1 parameter?  What about using a register constraint? Warning: I have not tried this, but what about something like `asm("ldp x8, x9, [%0, %1]" : : "r" (somePointer), "i"(16) : "x8", "x9");`?

Comment: Fixed this - it should obviously read %0. Extracted from a longer statement with more inputs / outputs, and forgot to update the argument :-)

Aren't those hints kind of important for the compiler, so that it knows which memory regions are accessed by my code? e.g. if I'm using it in a write context, the compiler probably needs to know which memory regions I have clobbered - in which case, the register constraint will not work?

Comment: True enough.  So since the compiler does not actually parse the asm, you can do: `asm("ldp x8, x9, [%0, %1]" : : "r" (somePointer), "i"(16), "m" (*somePointer) : "x8", "x9");` (ie have the constraint, but don't reference it).  Or add the "memory" clobber.  Note that as written, you are only telling the compiler that the asm *reads* the memory, not that it changes it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an ARM 64-bit toolchain to test this with, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
asm("ldp x8, x9, %0\n\t"
    :
    : "Ump" (*((__int128 *) somePointer + 1))
    : "x8", "x9");
```

The `Ump` constraint limits the memory operand to those permitted by the integer LDP instruction, otherwise it works like the `m` constraint. If `somePointer` is already a pointer to a 128-bit type you can just use `somePointer[1]` as the operand.

If the above doesn't work then David Wohlferd's suggestion should:

```
asm("ldp x8, x9, [%0, %1]" 
    : 
    : "r" (somePointer), "i"(16), "m" (*somePointer) 
    : "x8", "x9");
```